# How to obtain an entered data in a form inside Ajax.ActionLink?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

My page is quite simple. It shows a picture and has a comment section (which is a partial view). I only want the partial view to refresh whenever a new comment has been submitted. So I have this:

```
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("NewComment")</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Submit", "InsertComment", new
            {
               Id = Model.userParticipation.Id,
               CurrentPosition = 0,
               CurrentComments = Model.currentComments,
               NewCommentText = "???"
            },
           new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "CommentSection"
            })
        </tr>
```

The only prolem I have is that I don't know how to pass the entered text in the NewComment TextBox to the NewCommentText variable (instead of the "???" string). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need ajax begin form , not ajax.action link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Ajax.ActionLink` is going to generate the markup for an anchor tag (with ajaxified behavior wired in). But since you want to submit a new comment to the server, you need an input field for user to enter the comment and potentially a form. If you want the ajaxified behavior for this form submission, you can use the `Ajax.BeginForm` helper method.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("InsertComment", "Home", new
{
    Id = Model.userParticipation.Id,
    CurrentPosition = 0,
}, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "CommentSection"
}))
{
    <label>Enter comment</label>
    <input type="text" name="NewCommentText" />
    <input type="submit" />
}
<div id="CommentSection"></div>
```

This will generate the form tag with an input element with name attribute value set to "NewCommentText".

This should work assuming your `InsertComment` action method (inside HomeController) has a parameter with the same name as the input field, along with the other paramters like `Id` and `CurrentPosition`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InsertComment(string NewCommentText,int Id,int currentPosition)
{
    // to do : Save and return some valid markup
    return Content("To do : Replace this with useful html markup");
}
```

Comment: Cool! Glad i could help.